# Prevent auto unload of dll with boost shared_library.hpp

Tags: boost, shared-libraries

The documentation of boost shared_library.hpp suggests that the loaded dll or shared lib is auto unloaded when the shared_library object is destroyed. Is there a way to prevent this unloading to happen ?

Comment: Didn't you just tell yourself how to do it, or rather what to prevent?

Answer (score 0):

Yup. As you say, don't destroy the `shared_library` object.

Easiest way to achieve it is to allocate dynamically, and pass the pointer to the new owner when required.

To prevent resource memory headaches, usually some kind of smart pointer is used, like `std::unique_ptr`